# SQL Server - Why wont restore complete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to copy a live database from one instance to a development instance  for debugging purposes

The live database is ~200M in size running on on SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.4042)

I have tried numerous ways of backing up and restoring, but every time the Restore gets 100% and just sits there

I have tried SQLServer 2016 Developer and SQLServer 2008 R2  Express as development instance , same result

The database is very simple, but something is  blocking the restore

```
BACKUP DATABASE [database] TO DISK = N'D:\file.BAK' 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 5*
```

The backup literally takes seconds takes seconds, even with compression off it is only 200M in size

The restore takes a few seconds  to restore but then just sits at 100%

I have read many articles , none work so tried RECOVERY NORECOVERY

Tried to kill and restore, tried to mount, nothing seems to work.
What other options are there?

RESTORE DATABASE [database] FROM DISK = N'D:\File.BAK' WITH FILE = 1, MOVE N'Instance_Data' TO N'D:..\database.mdf', MOVE N'Instance_log' TO N'D:..\database_1.ldf', NOUNLOAD, RECOVERY, STATS = 5

Live database for Rows Data = 173 MB, the LOG 161,574 MB

Comment: Post your `RESTORE` statement.

Comment: How big is the LDF file on the live db?

Comment: Try taking a CHECKPOINT before the RESTORE?  It sounds like you have a large transaction log that is being rolled forward after the restore completes, and this can take a considerable time to execute...  You could also try putting the database into simple recover mode, and/ or shrinking the log file before backing it up.

Comment: OK .,sorry for the delay  I tried to find a way of editing original question to add additional information as requested                                                                                                                RESTORE DATABASE [database] FROM  DISK = N'D:\File.BAK' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'Instance_Data' TO N'D:\..\database.mdf',  MOVE N'Instance_log' TO NN'D:\..\database.mdf',  NOUNLOAD, RECOVERY, STATS = 5

Comment: Live database Rows Data = 173 MB, the LOG 161,574 MB

Comment: 161Gb log file, I would try as @RichardHansell has advised, or, ship the log, shrink it then back up the DB and try the restore. Sounds like that live DB isn't having its log file looked after.

Comment: @SteveHurst there's an edit button under the tags of your post, you should move your comment with additional information to the post, as it's important information that shouldn't live in a comment

Comment: OK spoke to the DBA he will take  look. He was  a bit surprised they have grown to such a size . Adding a 5 or 60 second  checkpoint didn't seem to have any effect .  . Not sure how to put database in recover mode, recover complains database is in restore mode